# Pandas returns UnicodeDecodeError:

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, gzip

While executing below code:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [{"id":"1","nazwa":"ĄĆĘŁŻŹąćęłżź"},
    {"id":"2","nazwa":"nazwa2"},
    {"id":"3","nazwa":"nazwa3"}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df.to_csv("file1.csv.gz", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', compression="gzip", 
index=False)
```

pandas returns:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
>   17: character maps to

I checked and when compression is not set, this code works, so probably the error is caused by gzip. Probably I need to update some packages, but I don't know which one.

Comment: For me working nice under python 3.6 and pandas 0.23.4

Comment: I got the same result, on my own machine. Problem is this code, does not work on production server, which is setup on ubuntu. This code works even with python 3.5, on my own computer. Probably the problem is some packages, but I don't know which one.

Comment: What's the version of Python and Pandas on the server?

Comment: Python 3.5, pandas 0.23.0

Comment: OK, problem solved. Pip has installed pandas 0.23.0 by default. After upgrading to 0.23.4 everything works fine.